# Getting a "-1#IND" error

Tags: c++

Getting the error in this line `double b3 = pow(log(abs(pow((y / z), 1.0 / 3.0))), 0.3);`
Can't figure out why, if the value inside of log() is always positive
Here the code:

```
double x = 0.48 * 5, y = 0.47 * 5, z = -1.32 * 5;
    void Count::Fn_b(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double b1 = x*x + z*z / pow(tan(pow(abs(x), 2.0)), 2.0);
        double b2 = 3 + x + y*y / Factr(2) + pow(z, 3.0) / Factr(3);
        double b3 = pow(log(abs(pow((y / z), 1.0 / 3.0))), 0.3);
        b = b1 / b2 + b3;
    }
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem?

Comment: I would guess that `pow` function does not works here because `z` is negative... Have you read the documentation? And what does it say? And if an expression as complex as the one above, don't give the expected result, then **why are you not trying to split it in simple expression first** to see where the problem is. I recommend you to make much more efforts... otherwise you don't learn anything and even ruin your reputation as you get poor voting for your question. **If you choose to be a programmer, then you have to work hard, very hard.**

Comment: The problem is -ve 1st parameter and second parameter less than 1 for `pow`. You can think of taking square root of -ve number.

Comment: @Phil1970, yeap, you were right. It doesn't work cause of negative z. Is there anoher way bring to a degree negative values?

Answer (score -1):

Well, for a power like 1/3 (or any other fractional power with an odd denominator), you can easily adjust your code to test if the value is negative and if so, take the absolute value of that, that the appropriate root and then multiply the result by -1. **Very basic mathematics that every programmer should be able to do.**

For example: `(-27)^(1/3) = -(27^(1/3)) = -3`.

In other case, you have to works with complex numbers. For example: `(-4)^(1/2)` is equal to `-2i` (where i is an imaginary number such that `i^2` is equal to `1`.

This is why, you should always listen to the mathematic teacher at school...